# How to make this code more efficient?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

As i am not very advanced in C# yet, I try to learn how to make my code more efficient.
I stored a lot of strings in some of the properties.

At the start of the application, i load all the seperatie properties into the textboxes.
I now ise this code to load them all:

```
private void LoadStoredStrings()
{
    txtT1S1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L1;
    txtT1S2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L2;
    txtT1S3.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L3;
    txtT1S4.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L4;
    txtT1S5.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L5;
    txtT1S6.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L6;
    txtT1S7.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L7;
    txtT1S8.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L8;
    txtT1S9.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L9;
    txtT1S10.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.strT1L10;
}
```

Obvious i can see the logic that each stored propertie ending with `T1L1` also fits to the txt that ends with `T1S1`.
I just know this should be done in a more elegant and solid way than what i did now.
Could anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: There is a rule of thumb that goes: "if you have to do something more than three times, use a loop" (or so). Same here, use a list-like container (e.g. `ListBox`) with just a `TextBlock` inside and (preferably) bind the collection to the `ListBox`. Assuming that you could also write the strings to the settings as some kind of collection.

Comment: mm im not sure, the sure will be able to put in the fields, and also save them back to the properties afterwards, so next time he loads the application, the changed strings are loaded again.

Comment: I'm a "winforms" guy so I don't do much in WPF. But in winforms you can bind a control's property (in this case .Text) to an application setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can bind your properties directly to your textboxes

```
<UserControl xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace.Properties" >


<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=strT1L1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: im getting some errors with this code. I needed to put a , behind the first }. After that i get an error saying "Type Properties:Settings' was not found". also its saying "path" is not allowed after a closing } of a markupExtension

Comment: It says it works 2 way, but when i just change te line and restart the app. it was not saved ?

Comment: if you wanna save your stuff you have to call Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); at least on closing or Application.Exit event

Answer (score 0):

If you can get all of those constants into a `List<string>`, you could use it to bind to an `ItemsControl` with `TextBlock` inside:

**Code behind or View Model**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _defaultProperties = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> DefaultProperties
{
    get { return _defaultProperties; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultProperties"}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <!--Just saying "Binding" allows binding directly to the current data context vs. a property on the data context-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```